# Работа со списками

Tags: c

Из стандартного потока ввода читается текст до ситуации конец файла. Надо вывести 10 самых часто встречаемых слов.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int value;
    char *wr;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

char *copyword(int i,int k, char *p){
    char *newword;
    int j;
    newword=(char*)malloc(k*sizeof(char));
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        newword[j]=p[j];
    }
    free(p);
    p=newword;
    return newword;
}

char *llist(int *er){
    int c,k=10,i=0;
    char *p;
    p=(char*)malloc(k*sizeof(char));
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        if (c!=' '){
            if(k==i){
                k=k*2;
                p=copyword(i+1,k,p);
            }
            p[i]=c;
            i++;
        }
    }
    *er=1;
    p[i]=0;
    p=copyword(i+1,i,p);
    return p;
}


Node *form(int *er,Node *list){
    char *word;
    Node *a,*b;
    word=llist(er);
    if(list==NULL){
        list=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(*list));
        list->wr=word;
        list->value++;
        list->next=NULL;
    }
    else{
        a=list;
while(a->next!=NULL){
            if(word==a->wr)
                a->value++;
            else
           a=a->next;
        }
        b=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(*list));
        b->value++;
        b->wr=word;
        b->next=NULL;
        a->next=b;
    }
    return list;
}


int main(){
    int er=0,*max,j,i,*p[9]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    Node *a;
    Node *first=NULL;
    while(er==0)
        first=form(&er,first);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    a=first;
    max=first->value;
    while(a->next!=NULL){
        a=a->next;
        if(max<a->value){
            max=a->value;
            p[i]=max;
        }
   }
   for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(p[j]!=max);
        a=first;
        while(a->next!=NULL){
             if(max==a->value)
                  break;
             else
                  a=a->next;
        }
        printf("%s\n",a->wr);
   }
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И в чем, собственно вопрос?

Comment: Программа не работает. Выдает какую-то ересь.....А поправить никак не получается.

Comment: Толком опишите в вопросе, что хотите увидеть, а что видите и на каких входных данных, тогда кто-нибудь точно ответит.

Comment: Хочу я увидеть 10 самых часто встречаемых слов. Моя программа обединяет все введеные слова в одно и выводит его много раз

Comment: Для начала, вот здесь `if(word==a->wr)` Вы сравниваете адреса, а не сами слова. Для сравнения слов используйте `strcmp()`.

Comment: Нам запрещено испольщывать библиотечные функции str....

Comment: Напишите свой эквивалент. Это несложно.

Comment: И раз уж используете `malloc()`, то посмотрите заодно на `realloc()` (видимо его лучше использовать вместо `copyword()`)

Comment: realloc() - тоже нельзя использывать)

Comment: malloc можно, а realloc нельзя? Это уже явный маразм.  Тоже  придется делать самостоятельно. Кстати, прочел в комментарии к ответу полную формулировку. Мне кажется, что проще отказаться от списка, а вместо него реализовать динамически расширяющийся массив (malloc/realloc) указателей на Ваши структуры (malloc) с  не повторяющимися словами (каждое тоже в памяти по malloc/realloc). Думаю, что сортировать массив Вам пока будет проще, чем список. Но это только лишь совет, окончательный выбор структуры данных, естественно, за Вами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пока ваш вопрос не закрыли, так как вы не сформулировали ясно вопрос, я укажу, что ваша программа совершенно не корректна.

Я не буду рассматривать всю программу. Достаточно уже будет убедиться, что функция `main` содержит множество ошибок и делает совсем не то, что требуется.

Допустим, что вы каким-то чудом:) правильно заполнили список, или по крайней мере, что этот список содержит какую-то осмысленную информацию после выполнения данной части функции `main`

```
int main(){
    int er=0,*max,j,i,*p[9]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    Node *a;
    Node *first=NULL;
    while(er==0)
        first=form(&er,first);
```

Можно предположить, что переменная `first` является указателем на первый узел списка.

Далее у вас идет цикл, который содержит 10 итераций, то есть переменная `i`  изменяется от 0 до 9 включительно

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
```

Но при этом для каждого значения `i` записывается некоторое значение в элемент массива `p` с индексом, равным значению `i`

```
        p[i]=max;
```

Однако, как видно из объявления массива `p`, он содержит только 9 элементов

```
    int er=0,*max,j,i,*p[9]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
                      ^^^^^
```

Следовательно, будет предпринята попытка записи в память за пределами данного массива, когда значение переменной `i` будет равно 9.

В данном фрагменте кода

```
a=first;
max=first->value;
while(a->next!=NULL){
    a=a->next;
    if(max<a->value){
        max=a->value;
        p[i]=max;
    }
```

}

производится поиск максимального значения адреса, хранящегося в указателях `value`.  Очевидно, что вам надо найти не максимальный адрес, а максимальное значение, адресуемое этими указателями. Причем вы всегда будете получать одно и то же значение в этом фрагменте, так как ничего в нем не меняется. То есть переменная `max` всегда будет иметь максимальное значение адреса, хранимое в полях `value`.

Более того, если это максимальное значение хранится в первом элементе списка, то переменная `p[i]` вообще не получит никакого значения и будет равна 0, так как присвоение происходит только при условии

```
    if(max<a->value){
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
        max=a->value;
        p[i]=max;
    }
```

Следующий за этим фрагментом цикл

```
   for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(p[j]!=max);
        a=first;
        while(a->next!=NULL){
             if(max==a->value)
                  break;
             else
                  a=a->next;
        }
        printf("%s\n",a->wr);
   }
```

также не имеет смысла хотя бы из-за этой точки с запятой в конце `if` предложения

```
        if(p[j]!=max);
                    ^^^
```

Я думаю, что алгоритм должен быть следующим. Вам надо ввести в список все слова, встречающиеся в тексте, а затем отсортировать его по убыванию частоты встречающихся слов. Первые десять элементов списка дадут вам искомый результат.

Comment: @mango44, слова, которые дублируются (те, счетчик которых Вы увеличиваете) повторно заносить в список не стоит.